# Automatically prompt to decrypt external LUKS filesystem in GNOME session?

Tags: gnome, luks

I have a LUKS filesystem on a USB hard drive and I'd like to have the system generate a GUI prompt whenever the device is connected to the computer to provide the decryption password, then mount the enclosed filesystem according to instructions in `/etc/fstab`.

Is there a way to do this? Does there exist a program which will, upon detecting the LUKS filesystem's UUID, prompt for a password, decrypt, then mount the volume in a special place, or do I have to rely on typing out `cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdXY && mount -a` every time I insert my device?

Comment: I don't know how helpful this is, but by default, Xfce pops up a dialogue box asking for a password when a LUKS-encrypted volume is connected.

Comment: @EmmaV That's helpful, I wish other WMs thought of this.

Comment: @NaftuliKay - this is old, but Gnome (3/Shell) does this as well now. It pops up a blocking password prompt whenever you connect a LUKS encrypted device. Not sure if you can configure it to mount as specified in `/etc/fstab` but we should be able to find out if you're still curious (after three years :p)